# laravel 5.7 What arguments accept this function $browser->type()

Tags: php, laravel

What arguments accept this function  `$browser->type()` and  what order I have to put them in ??? . I tried use it in this way

```
 $browser->type('#email.panel-control',$user->email)
```

and **I got an error**. What am I doing wrong ?

Edit: Error:

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body
>   textarea[name='input#email.form-control']"}

Comment: show us error..

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/dusk#generating-tests

Comment: I will add more that  I use it whit another arguments like  $browser->type('email', $user->email) and I got an error too .

Comment: first version  and an error   $browser->type('input#email.form-control',$user->email)  Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body textarea[name='input#email.form-control']"}

Comment: and second version $browser->type($user->email,'input#email.form-control')   , and an error  Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body textarea[name='udalosie@laravel.com']"}

Comment: `$browser->type('input#email.form-conrol',$user->email)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Laravel Dusk documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/dusk):

```
$browser->type('email', 'taylor@laravel.com');
```

You give it the `name` of your input field/textarea and the value you want to "*type*" into that field.

"*Note that, although the method accepts one if necessary, we are not required to pass a CSS selector into the type method. If a CSS selector is not provided, Dusk will search for an input field with the given name attribute. Finally, Dusk will attempt to find a textarea with the given name attribute.*"

In your case, an `<input>` field with name `#email.panel-control` could not be found, attempting to locate a `<textarea>` with name `#email.panel-control` also failed, that's why you get the error.